# Find object keys that begin with one of the strings in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Note: obviously, this can "easily" be done with multiple nested `foreach()` loops, however I am looking for a way that is less expensive (and, if possible, also less spagetti).

Given a data array of objects like this:

```
$data (array)
   [] (obj)
      ->id
      ->name
      ->a_one
      ->a_two
      ->b_three
      ->b_four
      ->c_five
   [] (obj)
      ...
```

and this array of matching prefixes:

```
$prefixes (array)
   [] (str) "a_"
   [] (str) "b_"
   [] (str) "c_"
```

how can I find (and unset) all properties of all objects in `$data` that begin with one of the defined `$prefixes`, **without using multiple `foreach()` loops?**

Solution using `foreach()`:

```
foreach($data as $datakey => $obj) {
   foreach($prefixes as $prefix) {
      foreach($obj as $property => $value) {
         if(strpos($property, $prefix) === 0) {
            unset($data[$datakey]->{$property});
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a regexp pattern that matches all of the prefixes, and check each key against the regexp:

```
$pattern = "^(" . join("|", $prefixes) . ")";
foreach($data as $datakey => $obj) {

foreach($data as $datakey => $obj) {
    foreach($obj as $property => $value) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $property))
            ...
    }
}
```

This still requires two loops, but there is no redundancy; each object in your data is examined only once. If you were to find a way to loop over all the objects' contents without two PHP loops, it will still take just as many steps. The code in your question looped over each object multiple times (once for each prefix), which is indeed redundant.

Comment: This is very interesting. Would you say that a single `preg_match()` is also less expensive than the redundancy created by the third `foreach()` loop? (In the case of very few $prefixes, and potentially very many $data objects with a lot of properties each, I'm leaning towards yes... but I'd like to hear your thoughts.)

Comment: To my knowledge @bobsoap it depends on the amount of iterations, I believe `foreach` (someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) is less expensive than regex over most datasets but regex provides a cleaner solution. I think if you had a large prefix dataset then regex would outperform a standard `foreach`, but otherwise `foreach` probably wins out on this one.

Comment: @bobsoap, the number of objects in `$data` is not important, since it's a constant factor for both approaches. My thoughts are not to micro-optimize for no reason. A regexp is in principle a one-pass solution, so use it and **if** you should ever have a performance problem, **then profile your entire program** and find out where the real bottle-necks are.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you'll prefer this or not but;

```
$prefixes = ['a_', 'b_'];

$filtered = array_map(function($object) use ($prefixes) {
    return unsetPrefixedProperties($object, $prefixes);
}, $data);

function unsetPrefixedProperties($object, $prefixes) {
    $regex = '/('. implode('|', $prefixes) .').+/';
    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match($regex, $key)) {
            unset($object->{$key});
        } 
    }

    return $object;
}
```

Similar to alexis basically using regex to match, removing the need to loop through your prefixes. Utilising array map to form a new array of filtered objects just because in my personal opinion it seems cleaner and finally extracted the other loop into its own function just to improve readability.

Still not perfect, but it's a start.

Edit: [Sandbox Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/041df1be29bc300ef7943322a5e1b7c1044341ad)

Comment: Great solution, thank you! I like how elegant this is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$matchedKeys = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($prefixes as $val) {
        $length = strlen($val);

            if (substr($key, 0, $length) === $val) {
                $matchedKeys[] = $key;
            }
    }
}
The $matchedKeys array will hold the matching keys from object $data.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but $data is an array of objects. Outside of that, your answer is essentially the same as my foreach() solution.